# Get complexity data for lines of a file - Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

The complexity view of Sonarqube shows the complexity value of an entire file. Is it possible to get the drilled down data of the complexity of a file. For example complexity of a file with complexity values of each line or complexity values of blocks of code etc.

Since the complexity is calculated based on an algorithm I think it is possible to get the drilled down data.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity at the method level is available only through the rule [Methods should not be too complex](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-1541), which measures Cyclomatic Complexity and through [Cognitive Complexity of methods should not be too high](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-3776). Both of these rules accept threshold parameters and will raise issues on methods that cross the respective thresholds. When such issues are raised, each line that contributes complexity to the method is annotated with its respective value.

If you *really* want to see the complexity of *each* line and method, turn these rules on with their threshold set to 0*.

<sup>* This is not a practice I would normally recommend.</sup>